# empty vars when method is called from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

On main delegate, I am executing some functions and getting some results for the variables. Then, I am calling from main delegate a function of another class `viewController1`. It is been executed properly but then, when I need to callback from `viewController1` to `appDelegate`, I create an instance:

```
AppDelegate *theInstance = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];

[AppDelegate composeBar:YES];
```

`ComposeBar` is properly called but then, most of variables, that were set at the beggining, are empty! Vars are retained allocated and synthezised but when callback are empty!

Comment: Why are you creating a new AppDelegate object? Where are you creating it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not alloc another instance of your appDelegate. If you want to access it you can use `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] composeBar:YES];`